# stm32 keil cannot assign array in interrupt

Tags: stm32, interrupts, keil

I can not assign my array in interrupt.

My main.c function is like this:

```
volatile uint32_t buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
int main(void)
{
  while(1)
  {
    sprintf((char*)string,"%d",buffer[0]);
    BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAt(250, LINE(9), (uint8_t *)string, LEFT_MODE);
  }
}
```

Interrupt routine is like this:

```
void EXTI3_IRQHandler(void)
{
    buffer[0] = 100;
}
```

The display always shows 0!

The strange thing is that when I use a variable instead of an array everything works fine!

```
uint32_t variable;
int main(void)
{
  while(1)
  {
    sprintf((char*)string,"%d",variable);
    BSP_LCD_DisplayStringAt(250, LINE(9), (uint8_t *)string, LEFT_MODE);
  }
}
```

```
void EXTI3_IRQHandler(void)
{
    variable = 100;
}
```

The display shows 100! Why can't I use array in interrupt routine?

Comment: Have you tried anything to find the cause? Like single-stepped the code in debugger?

Comment: Is `NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI3_IRQn)` ever called?

Comment: Yes, it is called as variable shows.

Comment: What happens if you remove volatile?

Comment: Nothing changes.

Comment: Maybe BUFFER_LENGTH is not defined correctly?

Comment: No, it is defined to 100